# Add styles to dynamically downloaded images in iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, interface-builder, quartz-graphics

My question is: Since I have an app that downloads images from TMDB (the movie database) and I can't edit them in Photoshop before adding them to my application I was wondering if there was a way to add effects. Like a nice drop shadow and a 1 pix border to my images dynamically as they are downloaded or referenced from within application? (during development)

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I'm probably looking in the wrong place though. 
Any help?

Comment: Have you read section 6 of the [TMDB terms of use](http://www.themoviedb.org/terms-of-use)?

Comment: @Caleb Can I not pull their Movie covers into my app using the API? http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1

Comment: Didn't realize they have an API. Looks like they also have another [terms of service](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/terms-of-use) document, too. I'm just saying... make sure you have permission before you pull content from someone else's site.

Comment: @Caleb Oh, Totally. I'll apply for a commercial licence (which is free I guess) and jump through all appropriate hoops. The last thing I need is legal issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do all that using [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html).

Comment: The images are in a UIScrollView like the App Store Screenshots view. Would this be possible to add to every image so that there is no flash of unstyled content. (I'm an extreme beginner, sorry if that is a stupid question)

Comment: @Taylor: You're wanting a preload?

Comment: @sudo rm -rf      Well, it that is what it takes so that when the image is scrolled into view it already has it's shadow and such then yes. I really wouldn't know.